# Find and replace values in a list that don't match values in another list [Java]

Tags: java, string, list, replace, position

so this is the problem that I am having.

I have this list of values

```
ArrayList<String> song = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("E", "D", "C", "D", "E", "E", "E", "D", "D", "D", "E", "G", "G"));
```

Then I have a list of lists of the same type

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> population = new ArrayList<>();
```

and the values are being added in that list from this list in random order

```
ArrayList<String> notes = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("C", "C#", "D", "Eb", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "Bb", "B"));
```

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    {
        ArrayList<String> songInPopulation = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int j = 0; j < song.size(); j++) {
           songInPopulation.add(notes.get(rand.nextInt(notes.size())));
        }
        population.add(songInPopulation);

    }
}
```

So at the end I can have for example a list of 5 lists of the following values

List A = [Bb, G#, G, Eb, C, G, C#, A, F#, F, Bb, C, Eb]

List B = [F#, G#, E, Bb, D, Bb, G, Bb, G, Bb, C#, Eb, C#]

List C = [Eb, C#, F#, B, C#, G#, F, C, F#, C, C#, D, B]

List D = [Bb, A, Bb, F#, Eb, E, A, Eb, A, G#, D, F#, D]

List E = [F#, Bb, Bb, A, Bb, Bb, G#, G#, D, C, E, F#, G]

I am iterating through these lists, search for matches and saving them into a list of integers that are positions where the matches happened and I am also counting matches

```
Integer fitCounter = 0;
Integer maxFitCounter = 0;
Integer positionMax = 0;

ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> positionsList = new ArrayList\<\>();

for (int i = 0; i < population.size(); i++) {
fitCounter = 0;
ArrayList<Integer> positions = new ArrayList<>();
for (int j = 0; j < song.size(); j++) {

        if (song.get(j).equals(population.get(i).get(j))) {
    
            fitCounter++;
            positions.add(j);
    
        }
        
        if (fitCounter > maxFitCounter) {
            maxFitCounter = fitCounter;
            positionMax = i;
        }
    }
    positionsList.add(positions);

}
```

Now I want to do is replace Strings/Notes within these 5 lists where they didn't match with the random values from the initial list.

I tried to do this, but it didn't work, it's replace all the strings in the lists

```
for (int i=0;i<population.size();i++){

    for (int j=0;j< song.size();j++){
    
        for (int k=0;k<positionsList.get(i).size();k++){
            if (j!=positionsList.get(i).get(k)){
                population.get(i).set(j,notes.get(rand.nextInt(notes.size())));
    
            }
        }
    
    }

}
```

Comment: So ```positionList[i]``` means where matches happened for each ```population[i]```? Then it comes natural that ```j!=positionsList.get(i).get(k)``` is true in some cases for each ```population[i]```. Btw, It helps a lot if you can trace varibles by debugger or printing them.

Comment: Yes, so it's like this for example
Initial song: [E, D, C, D, E, E, E, D, D, D, E, G, G]

List of songs: 
[B, A, B, C, A, F#, B, B, Bb, G#, F, Bb, C],
[B, F#, Bb, E, C, A, G#, A, F, A, C, A, C#],
[F, Eb, G#, G#, G#, G#, B, Bb, Eb, G, C#, D, G#],
[F#, F, Bb, G, D, C, E, G#, C#, F, Bb, C#, C],
[A, C, F#, Eb, C#, D, A, D, D, F, D, F#, D]

PositionsList
[7, 8],
[6],
[],
[],
[]

That is that's the list of list of positions where matches happened